# How to remove extra list from the result in python

Tags: python

Result has extra brackets, how can I remove them in `python`?

I am calling two methods where one returns a tuple of dictionaries and the second returns a list of tuples of dictionaries.

```
print method_A() // ({'id': 6}, {'id': 9})
print method_B() // [({'id': 6}, {'id': 9})]
```

How can I remove the list from the result of second method?

I tried it with type checking and has worked but I want to know if there is any easy to way to do it.

I tried following code:

```
resultA = method_A() // ({'id': 6}, {'id': 9})
resultB method_B() // [({'id': 6}, {'id': 9})]

if type(resultA) == list:
    resultA = resultA[0]
if type(resultB) == list:
    resultB = resultB[0]
```

or directly I can use resultB[0] if I know it

Comment: And fixing `method_B` instead is not an option?

Comment: Did you write the methods?

Comment: Can you show us the methods

Comment: i am using third party method. So i have no option to change return value of methods.

Comment: sorry i can't show you methods

Comment: Fixing `method_B()` would be the best way, but if you can't fix `method_B()` (i.e., it's in a library that you have no control over), then using `resultB[0]` would certainly work.  If you're **always** going to only get one result set back, you could even call it as `resultB = method_B()[0]` to avoid dealing with a list.

Comment: Methods are called base on some condition so i have to check result type. And I have to pass it to another methods. So i am finding easy way like casting result. here i can't cast result due to extra list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of these methods *always* returns a list with the tuple element, just use indexing:

```
resultA = method_A()
resultB = method_B()[0]
```

If either method *sometimes* returns a list object and sometimes just the tuple, use a function:

```
def unwrap(v):
    v[0] if isinstance(v, list) else v
```

and use that:

```
resultA = unwrap(method_A())
resultB = unwrap(method_B())
```

Then contact whomever created those methods and talk to them sternly about consistency in API design.

Comment: Thanks. I already talked with those guys they are trying. Hope they will provide consistency in API.